# Google Adsense are not showing on my website when i open it on desktop but showing well on smart phones as i am using "sahifa v4.0" wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, adsense

Ads are not showing on my website when i open it on desktop but showing well on smart phones as I am using "sahifa v4.0" wordpress theme.

My website is http://itsmyfun.net . One Ad is in header section and one is just before footer section. Third is before the article.

Kindly guide me how can i solve this problem?

Ads are visible at mobile devices you can check here:  http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

Answer (score 1):

You have some problem in the part of the HTML embedding the Ads. Take a look:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var adWidth = jQuery(document).width();
google_ad_client = "5467995485431950";
if ( adWidth >= 768 ) {
  google_ad_slot    = "";
  google_ad_width   = 728;
  google_ad_height  = 90;
} else  if ( adWidth >= 468 ) {
  google_ad_slot    = "";
  google_ad_width   = 468;
  google_ad_height  = 60;
}else {
  google_ad_slot    = "";
  google_ad_width   = 300;
  google_ad_height  = 250;
}
</script>
```

You should cleanup the first google_ad_slot, that is related to big screens. Here's why it works on smaller screens (you can also see for yourself if you reload the page with the window resized)

Comment: Sir i have replaced my code with this but the result is same. Ads are visible at mobile devices but not at desktop and Tablets.

Comment: I had posted your code to show you the error, I've edited it so that you can replace it and it should work.

Comment: I had replaced my adslot with your provided code but ads still are not displaying on desktop you can check it.
kindly analyze it again and help me.

Comment: following provided instructions helped me alot:

With the latest Google Adsense code, you only need to enter your Google AdSense ID which is the number beginning with "pub-". You may leave the Ad Channel field blank.

Comment: sorry, i don't get if it works or not, sorry for the delay